# Change node size of a tree

Tags: tikz-trees, trees

I have this tree:

[image]

That was created with this code:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[circle,draw]{}
            child{
                node[circle,draw]{a}
            }
            child[missing]{};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
```

How do I increase the size of the root circle so that, even when empty, it looks like the bottom circle? Or is there a better way to create these trees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With use of the `forest` package:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {circle,
            draw,
            minimum size=1.1em,
            inner sep=2pt,
            font=\small,
    l sep=9mm,
    s sep=6mm
            }
[
    [a]
    [, coordinate, no edge]
]   
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: is it possible to color the nodes?

Comment: @L.WD Yes. Tree nodes in forest are regular TikZ nodes. See the [`forest` documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/forest) for more information.

Comment: @L.WD, yes, it is possible. What you like to color? Node's'  borders? Nodes'  fill? Only particular node?

Comment: Fine! I got it! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply define the size of the tree nodes to have a minimum. Since it's likely that the majority of your nodes will also be drawn as circles, and you may have more than one tree that looks like this,  it makes sense to create a global style for re-use including all of those parameters.

If you're drawing a lot of trees, I would strongly recommend switching to `forest`. The base TikZ tree drawing tools are really not very usable: their syntax is very clunky and they do no automatic node packing.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{my tree/.style={every node/.style={draw,circle,minimum size=1.5em}}}\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[my tree]
            \node{}
            child{
                node{a}
            }
            child[missing]{};
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I will use also istgame package :)

Comment: @Sebastiano `istgame` is a great package, but it's really designed for a very specific purpose, game theory games. But for trees in computer science or linguistics, `forest` is almost certainly more useful.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the TeX.SE community. I will use, as a fast solution an hack, putting into `\node[circle,draw]{...}` a phantom character: `\phantom{\small a}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[circle,draw]{\phantom{\small a}}
            child{
                node[circle,draw]{a}
            }
            child[missing]{};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using it for another problem.

Comment: @L.WD I have write something very fast to solve your question. All the best.